# How to insert output into command line / function

Tags: r

I have output ("1b" "2b" "3b" ... "40b") The values are then inserted into a function for further calculations. I am prepping the values with the following code.

```
# delete column names
names(profile.ab)  <- NULL
# insert comma between values
 (profile.ab<-sub("([[:digit:]]{1,1})$", "\\1,", profile. ab))
# remove comma from last item
profile.ab [50] = "2"
# remove quotations
noquote(profile. ab)
# delete leading bracketed numbers
cat(profile.ab, "\n")
```

At this point I am cutting and pasting but it is a laborious task. I need the list redirected into a function automatically.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried calling your funtion with profile.ab? For instance like this `YourFunction(profile.ab)`?

Comment: The leading bracketed numbers are just from pretty-printing, they aren't actually in your data, so the `cat` is probably not needed.

Comment: tried calling it with the function and no go

Comment: I removed the leading brackets because I am cutting from the output and pasting back into the command line. I know the brackets aren't in the data